# Best way to pass data between forms using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, global-variables, parameter-passing

This is more of a theory based question. I am working on the design for my final project in C#, which is to create Jeopardy. My question is, what would be the best way to pass data between them? For instance, the rubric requires the game opens with an options screen after the splash shows. Here, they will select the number of players and their names. I know that in my gameform load event, I can just specify those things as parameters and pass them as arguments from the optionsform. This seems messy though, is there a more efficient way to create project wide variables that I could reference no matter the form I am currently using?

Thanks for any answers, it's always appreciated!

-- Young Padawan Coder

Comment: Global variables are generally considered bad practice. I would suggest reading up on MVC pattern. [Here's an article I just googled.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383153/The-Model-View-Controller-MVC-Pattern-with-Csharp) I only skimmed it, but it seems like a reasonable place to start.

Comment: Good stuff! Thanks Nick!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about creating a separate business object (i.e. class) with either static properties or singleton pattern. You would then store all your application values there and you can refer to them from anywhere in your application without the messy work of passing around variables all over the place.

Comment: This is the right answer. I see too many questions about accessing data between forms, and too many people explain how to make members public or pass a reference to the other form via a constructor, without addressing the fundamental problems with separation of concerns, layering and abstraction.

Comment: Thanks Sam, I will apply this to my project.